# Shifting leaf nodes to the right in forest

Tags: forest, linguistics

In the following tree the edges should hit the leaves above ha, en, and o. But due to the subscripts, the edges hit at the middle of the complete node.

[image: image showing problem: edges hitting top centre of whole leaf nodes]

I found a "solution" to the problem that inserts phantom text of the same size as the subscript to the left, but this has the disadvantage of making the node larger, which makes the spacing between nodes appear uneven:

[image: image showing result of unsatisfactory workaround: the extra spaces make the spacing between leaf nodes appear uneven]

Is there a way to shift the nodes to the right without making the nodes larger?

I also tried using \rlap, but this results in funny overlaps.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}

\newcommand{\sub}[1]{\(_{\mbox{\scriptsize\textrm{#1}}}\)}
\forestset{
     empty nodes/.style={
     delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for siblings={anchor=north}}{}}
     }
   }


    \begin{document}

\begin{forest}%sm edges
        for tree={s sep=-2.5}
[COMP-M
        [COPCOMP-M
                [{[ha]\sub{STM}}]
                [{[en]\sub{STM}}]
                [{[o]\sub{STM}},tier=word]
        ]
        [,empty nodes
                [{[ɑʀt\textsuperscript{s}t]},tier=word]
        ]
]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}%sm edges
        for tree={s sep=-2.5}
[COMP-M
        [COPCOMP-M
                [{\hphantom{\sub{STM}}[ha]\sub{STM}}]
                [{\hphantom{\sub{STM}}[en]\sub{STM}}]
                [{\hphantom{\sub{STM}}[o]\sub{STM}},tier=word]
        ]
        [,empty nodes
                [{[ɑʀt\textsuperscript{s}t]},tier=word]
        ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly related: I would probably change the pseudo-math `\(_{\mbox{\scriptsize\textrm{#1}}}\)` to `\textsubscript{\scriptsize\textrm{#1}}`.

You can use `\rlap` to set the width of the subscripts to zero an thus shift the node to the correct position. Due to the zero width, however, you would need to manually adjust the spacing between the nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}

\newcommand{\sub}[1]{\rlap{\textsubscript{\scriptsize\textrm{#1}}}}
\forestset{
    empty nodes/.style={
        delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for siblings={anchor=north}}{}}
    }
}
   
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}%sm edges
        for tree={s sep=3.25ex}
[COMP-M
        [COPCOMP-M
                [{[ha]\sub{STM}}]
                [{[en]\sub{STM}}]
                [{[o]\sub{STM}},tier=word]
        ]
        [,empty nodes
                [{[ɑʀt\textsuperscript{s}t]},tier=word]
        ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another way would be to manually set the `child anchor` to something between 90 (= north) and 135 (north west). The advantage of this solution is that you won't have the risk of overlapping elements that may require manual setting of the distances like in the solution above. The disadvantage is that it is less accurate.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}

\newcommand{\sub}[1]{\textsubscript{\scriptsize\textrm{#1}}}
\forestset{
    empty nodes/.style={
        delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for siblings={anchor=north}}{}}
    }
}
   
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}%sm edges
        for tree={s sep=1ex}
[COMP-M
        [COPCOMP-M
                [{[ha]\sub{STM}}, child anchor=120]
                [{[en]\sub{STM}}, child anchor=120]
                [{[o]\sub{STM}}, child anchor=120, tier=word]
        ]
        [,empty nodes
                [{[ɑʀt\textsuperscript{s}t]}, tier=word]
        ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A semi-general automatic solution. Comments in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{
  empty nodes/.style={
    delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for siblings={anchor=north}}{}}
  }
}


% flrlap = Forest Left/Right Lap
% 
% Like \llap and \rlap, but for Forest nodes.  The "\fllap"ed/"\frlap"ed part of the node
% will be "ignored" by parent--child edges, but taken into account in packing.
% 
% (This has been tested with south-growing trees with north--south edges, and
% calign=midpoint. It surely won't work in general.)
% 
\forestset{
  % (1) New options for the nodes.  They will hold the width of the left/right lap.
  declare dimen={fllap}{0pt},
  declare dimen={frlap}{0pt},
  flrlaps/.style={
    % (2) We have to improvise because Forest doesn't have an "after typesetting node"
    % hook.  So we'll (globally) append to macro \flrlaps while typesetting the nodes.
    % Let's empty it out before we start.
    before typesetting nodes={
      TeX={\gdef\flrlaps{}},
    },
    % See below for (3).
    % 
    % (4) Use the instructions gathered in \flrlaps to set fllap/flrap options of the
    % nodes containing \fllap/\frlap.
    before packing={
      TeX={\expandafter\forestset\expandafter{\flrlaps}},
    },
    for tree={
      % (5) This new edge path will take care of the parent--child edges.  The trick is to
      % xshift the edge ends by (fllap-frlap)/2.
      edge path'={%
        % The parent end.  We use an internal macro, \forestOve, to easily access the
        % parent options.
        ([xshift=(\forestOve{\forestoption{@parent}}{fllap}-
          \forestOve{\forestoption{@parent}}{frlap})/2]!u.parent anchor)
        --
        % The child end is easy.
        ([xshift=(\forestoption{fllap}-\forestoption{frlap})/2].child anchor)
      },
      % (6) We need to shift the children (in the s-dimension) for an appropriate amount.
      % Assume first, for simplicity, that we have a child aligned under the parent.  We
      % have to shift this child for (frlap-fllap)/2 (so just the negative of what we did
      % to the edge.)  But if our alignment point is between two children (as with the
      % default calign=midpoint), then this becomes (frlap_1+frlap_2-fllap_1-fllap_2)/4,
      % where the indices 1 and 2 refer to the primary and secondard calign child.
      % 
      % We only do this for nodes without children, obviously.
      if n children=0{}{
        % We need to do this adjustment immediately after packing the node.  If we didn't,
        % the subtrees, while packing, can be wider than those we get at the end, so
        % Forest would push them too much apart.
        after packing node={
          % We're at the parent node and want to add "(frlap_1+frlap_2-fllap_1-fllap_2)/4"
          % to "s" of all children.  What we're adding is constant, so we can precompute
          % it.  An "Ow+x+O", with one of the first four lines, accesses option
          % fllap/frlap of the calign primary/secondary child; "w4" than wraps these
          % values into the "s+" expression below.  The final part is easy, but what about
          % this "Ow+x+O"?
          % 
          % "Ow+x+O".  The first "O" gets the value of option "calign primary/secondary
          % child".  This value is the child number, and negative numbers start counting
          % at the last child.  We then "w"rap this child number into {!n...lap}, i.e. we
          % replace ##1 in there with the child number. "+x" expands this, with the sole
          % purpose of getting "n'" and "-<child number>" when the child number is
          % negative --- ahem, while option "calign primary/secondary child" accepts
          % negative numbers to count from the last child, the nodewalk step "n" doesn't.
          % We basically end up with "!n(')=<absolute child number>.fl/rlap", and this is
          % a nice "<relative node name>.<option>" for accessing fllap/frlap option of the
          % child with the specified number, which "+O" will then pick up. Uff.
          for children/.process=Ow+x+O Ow+x+O Ow+x+O Ow+x+O w4
            {calign primary child}{!n\ifnum##1<0 '\fi={\ifnum##1<0 -\fi##1}.fllap}
            {calign primary child}{!n\ifnum##1<0 '\fi={\ifnum##1<0 -\fi##1}.frlap}
            {calign secondary child}{!n\ifnum##1<0 '\fi={\ifnum##1<0 -\fi##1}.fllap}
            {calign secondary child}{!n\ifnum##1<0 '\fi={\ifnum##1<0 -\fi##1}.frlap}
            {s+=(##2+##4-##1-##3)/4},
        },
      },
    },
  }
}
% (3) These macros will be used inside the nodes, to indicate the material
% which should "stick out" at the left/right.
\def\fllap#1{%
  % Typeset the argument into a box.
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  % Globally append a forest instruction setting the fllap for this node to
  % \flrlaps.
  \xappto\flrlaps{for id={\forestoption{id}}{fllap+=\the\wd0},}%
  % Use the box.
  \unhbox0
}
\def\frlap#1{% Ditto.
  \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \xappto\flrlaps{for id={\forestoption{id}}{frlap+=\the\wd0},}%
  \unhbox0
}



\begin{document}

\begin{forest} flrlaps
  [COMP-M
    [COPCOMP-M, calign=2
      [{[ha]\frlap{\textsubscript{STM}}}]
      [{[en]\frlap{\textsubscript{STM}}}]
      [{[o]\frlap{\textsubscript{STM}}},tier=word]
    ]
    [,empty nodes
      [{\fllap{\textsubscript{LEFT-STM}}[art\textsuperscript{s}t]},tier=word]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest} flrlaps
  [COMP-M
    [COPCOMP-M
      [{[en]\frlap{\textsubscript{STM}}}]
      [{[o]\frlap{\textsubscript{STM}}},tier=word]
    ]
    [,empty nodes
      [{\fllap{\textsubscript{LEFT-STM}}[art\textsuperscript{s}t]},tier=word]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: result of compilation]